# Getting Angular Material to work with Webpack and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have an angular-typescript project that is being managed by webpack. I want to add the angular-material library to it, and I'm having big issues with this.

The html part of my code looks like this at the moment:

```
<div class="container">
  <my-app></my-app>
</div>

<script>
  require("zone.js");
</script>
<script src="../build/common.js"></script>
<script src="../build/angular2.js"></script>
<script src="../build/app.js"></script>
```

The first problem I ran into was that no matter where I put the `<script>` tags pointing to angular- aria, animate and material, chrome would always error with:

```
Cannot read property 'module' of undefined angular-aria.js:57 etc.
```

for all three angular-material librarys. I then assumed that angular was being loaded at some later point, causing the material libraries to not function correctly. I then tried writing a function that would run on `<body onload="loadAngMat()">` that called `require()` on each of the angular-material librarys, and it seemed to work, at first.

I then created a simple `<md-input-container>` in the template of one of my angular components. I could not find out what URL to load the ngMaterial Module from in my app's namespace. I used a standard `node install` to install the material libraries, so the structure (very condensed) looks a bit like this:

```
> app
    > app.module.ts
    > index.html
    > index.js
    > etc.
> build
    > built project
> node_modules
    > angular-material
        > index.js
    > angular-aria
        > angular-aria.js
    > angular-animate
        > angular-animate.js
    > other angular and node modules
```

To load the library into my angular project, I figured that I would simply use:

```
import { ngMaterial } from 'angular-material';
```

But without success. Now chrome says
`Template parse errors: md-input-container is not a known element.`

#### **So my question is, how do I load all the libraries correctly and get `app.module.ts` to load `ngMaterial`?**

Here is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,

  entry: {
    'angular2': [
      'rxjs',
      'reflect-metadata',
      '@angular/core'
    ],
    'app': './app/app.module',
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.ts','.js','.json', '.css', '.html']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts',
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'angular2', filename: 'angular2.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common',   filename: 'common.js' })
  ],
  target:'node-webkit'
};
```

I should also say that I tried loading the material libraries using this config file and I got a `a dependency to an entry point is not allowed` error when I built the project.

Comment: A message to everyone in the future: Just use the Angular-CLI. it will save you hours and hours of hellish webpack debugging.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen your code

```
import { ngMaterial } from 'angular-material';
```

and i found that you are using angular-material, This repository is used only for Angular Material v1.x not for angular 2.

for Angular 2 there is npm package called [@angular2-material](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material), please use this.

Comment: Ok cool, I have switched. However, when I run webpack, I get about 1000 errors about typescript definition files. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what kind of errors?
are you using angular-cli? if not i strongly recommends you to use angular-cli. it uses webpack.

Comment: the errors look like ERROR in /home/oscar/electron/electron-from-github/angular2-electron-master/node_modules/@angular/material/core/portal/portal.d.ts
(53,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.